# network security- cryptography

Tags: rsa

I was solving a RSA problem and facing difficulty to compute d 
plz help me with this

given p-971, q-52
    Ø(n) - 506340

```
gcd(Ø(n),e) = 1       1< e < Ø(n)
```

therefore gcd(506340, 83) = 1 
    e= 83 .

```
e * d mod Ø(n) = 1
```

i want to compute d , i have all the info 
can u help me how to computer d from this.
    (83 * d) mod 506340 = 1 
i am a little wean in maths so i am having difficulties finding d from the above equation.

Comment: 1. You probably have a typo in `q`, because it's not a prime and they are too small to create `"Ø(n)" = 506340`. 2. What programming language are you talking about? How about you try to solve it and come back with your partial results?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Given prime numbers p = 971 and q = 523, determine public and private keys (please show all your work!) and encrypt and decrypt the following plaintexts:

a. 128

Comment: @AbhayDeshmukh Your question would be more appropriate here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your value for `q` is not prime `52=2^2 * 13`. Therefore you cannot find `d` because the maths for calculating this relies upon the fact the **both** `p` and `q` are prime.

I suggest working your way through the examples given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29

Normally, I would hesitate to suggest a wikipedia link such as that, but I found it very useful as a preliminary source when doing a project on RSA as part of my degree.

You will need to be quite competent at modular arithmetic to get to grips with how RSA works. If you want to understand how to find `d` you will need to learn to find the `Modular multiplicative inverse` - just google this, I didn't come across anything incorrect when doing so myself.

Good luck.

**A worked example**

Let's take `p=11`, `q=5`. In reality you would use very large primes but we are going to be doing this by hand to we want smaller numbers. Keep both of these **private**.

Now we need `n`, which is given as `n=pq` and so in our case `n=55`. This needs to be made **public**.

The next item we need is the **totient** of `n`. This is simply `phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)` so for our example `phi(n)=40`. Keep this **private**.

Now you calculate the encryption exponent, `e`. Defined such that `1<e<phi(n)` and `gcd(e,phi(n))=1`. There are nearly always many possible different values of `e` - just pick one (in a real application your choice would be determined by additional factors - different choices of `e` make the algorithm easier/harder to crack). In this example we will choose `e=7`. This needs to be made **public**.

Finally, the last item to be calculated is `d`, the decryption exponent. To calculate `d` we must solve the equation `ed mod phi(n) = 1`. This is most commonly calculated using the **Extended Euclidean Algorithm**. This algorithm solves the equation `phi(n)x+ed=1` subject to `1<d<phi(n)`, where `x` is an unknown multiplicative factor - which is identical to writing the previous equation without using `mod`. In our particular example, solving this leads to `d=23`. This should be kept **private**.

Then your public key is: `n=55`, `e=7`
and your private key is: `n=55`, `d=23`

To see the workthrough of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm check out this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYasb426Yjk. The values used in that video are the same as the ones used here.

RSA is complicated and the mathematics gets very involved. Try solving a couple of examples with small values of `p` and `q` until you are comfortable with the method before attempting a problem with large values.

Comment: Given prime numbers p = 971 and q = 523, determine public and private keys (please show all your work!) and encrypt and decrypt the following plaintexts:

a. 128

Comment: this is the actual question

Comment: @AbhayDeshmukh See my edit. The youtube link is fairly decent but you will most likely end up watching several such videos before it starts to click.